# Weird line bug when animating a falling sprite using JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, sprite

I'm trying to move a block of butter down a canvas window. Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sandbox-forked-tygc5z?file=/index.html

The important code is index.js:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

window.onresize = function () {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};

const arr = ["butter", "bread", "cheese"];
const sprites = [];
const tilesheet = new Image();

const butter1 = {
  img: tilesheet,
  sourceWidth: 24,
  sourceHeight: 60,
  sourceX: 3,
  sourceY: 2,
  vy: 0,
  timer: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1,
  visible: false
};
const butter2 = {
  img: tilesheet,
  sourceWidth: 33,
  sourceHeight: 60,
  sourceX: 27,
  sourceY: 2,
  vy: 0,
  timer: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1,
  visible: false
};
const butter3 = {
  img: tilesheet,
  sourceWidth: 24,
  sourceHeight: 60,
  sourceX: 60,
  sourceY: 2,
  vy: 0,
  timer: 0,
  x: 60,
  y: 0,
  scale: 1,
  visible: false
};
tilesheet.addEventListener(
  "load",
  () => {
    arr.forEach((_, i) => {
      const b1 = { ...butter1 };
      b1.timer = i * 62;
      sprites.push(b1);

      const b2 = { ...butter2 };
      b2.x = b1.x + b1.sourceWidth * b1.scale;
      b2.timer = b1.timer;
      sprites.push(b2);

      const b3 = { ...butter3 };
      b3.x = b2.x + b2.sourceWidth * b2.scale;
      b3.timer = b2.timer;
      sprites.push(b3);
    });
    render();
  },
  false
);
tilesheet.src = "./src/sample.png";

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  //console.log(arr.length, sprites.length);
  sprites.forEach((sprite, i) => {
    sprite.timer -= 0.3;

    if (sprite.timer <= 0) {
      sprite.visible = true;
    }

    if (sprite.visible) {
      sprite.vy = 0.3;
      sprite.y += sprite.vy;
    }
  });
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(229, 242, 24, 1)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  sprites.forEach((sprite) => {
    if (sprite.visible) {
      ctx.drawImage(
        sprite.img,
        sprite.sourceX,
        sprite.sourceY,
        sprite.sourceWidth,
        sprite.sourceHeight,
        sprite.x,
        sprite.y,
        sprite.sourceWidth * sprite.scale,
        sprite.sourceHeight * sprite.scale
      );
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see in the code sandbox, there is a weird line appearing when the blocks of butter go down the window:
[image]
It is not there when the speed is 1 instead of 0.3 or when the butter is not moving.

Is there anyway I can get rid of the weird line? Thanks

Comment: I have no probleum running the code. https://prnt.sc/e48N_35pubGm

Comment: Floor your coordinates and disable image smoothing: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sandbox-forked-skv2k4?file=/src/index.js:0-2261

Comment: Note that if you need to transform your sprites in more complex ways (e.g rotate them), then you'd be better creating ImageBitmaps from these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457887/html-canvas-shows-tiny-slice-of-adjacent-image-in-tileset/69459221#69459221